# what is the minimal version of libcurl that supports TLS 1.2?

Tags: openssl, libcurl, tls1.2

I know that openssl supports TLS 1.2 since version 1.0.1.
But what is the earliest **libcurl** version that will successfully work with a TLS 1.2 server (using openssl 1.0.1 or above)?

I couldn't find this info in https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL didn't require anything special done in the client code to negotiate TLS 1.2, so the earliest possible curl version you could build with OpenSSL 1.0.1 could automatically speak TLS 1.2.

If I recall correctly, you could build curl with OpenSSL 1.0.1 fine on the release day, back in March 14 2012 (curl 7.24.0 was the latest curl release at the time) - but there's also a chance that you *could* build even earlier curl versions with that OpenSSL version...

None of this should be important to anyone because nobody anywhere should still be using that old versions of either curl or OpenSSL...